# ¿Como obtener padres e hijos en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

buen dia.
estoy teniendo un problemon para obtener los accesos de un usuario, quiero obtener los accesos y si este es hijo de un acceso padre, que tambien me traiga el acceso padre.
este es mi modelo relacional
[image: Estoy saltando roles, ya que puedo conectar rol persona con rol accesos directamente]

esta es la consulta que tengo actualmente

```
    SELECT *
FROM rolpersona rp JOIN rolaccesos ra ON rp.rol = ra.rol RIGHT JOIN accesos a ON ra.acceso = a.id 
WHERE persona = 7 OR a.acceso_padre = (SELECT s.id FROM accesos s WHERE s.id = a.acceso_padre)
ORDER BY a.acceso_padre ASC
```

---

Lo he logrado a traves de esta consula, pero siento que esta muy pesada la consulta, si alguien sabe como optimizarla, se lo agradeceria.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM accesos
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT a.id 
    FROM rolpersona rp JOIN rolaccesos ra ON rp.rol = ra.rol JOIN accesos a ON ra.acceso = a.id
    WHERE rp.persona = 7
) OR id IN (
    SELECT a.acceso_padre 
    FROM rolpersona rp JOIN rolaccesos ra ON rp.rol = ra.rol JOIN accesos a ON ra.acceso = a.id
    WHERE rp.persona = 7
)
```

Comment: Hola Carlos. ¿podrías por favor colocar un ejemplo de la salida esperada?

Comment: Por favor, agrega un ejemplo de los datos de entrada y la salida que esperas obtener con esos datos. Unas pocas filas son suficientes. Un saludo.

Comment: el dato de entrada el el id de la persona. y los datos que espero obtener son los accesos asignados al rol que tiene el usuario. (si el acceso es tiene como padre a otro acceso, que tambien me traiga este acceso). actualmente con la consulta que tengo me trae los accesos pero sin el padre

Answer (score 0):

puedes intentar agregando una subconsulta a un segundo join para el acceso padre
aqui definiras los campos necesarios pertenecientes al padre

el segundo join de accesso te dara los campos definidos en el select de tu subconsulta

ejemplo:

```
SELECT *
FROM rolpersona rp 
JOIN rolaccesos ra ON rp.rol = ra.rol 
LEFT JOIN accesos a ON ra.acceso = a.id 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id as idPadre,nombre as nombrePadre,activity as activityPadre 
   FROM accesos
) as TablaPadre ON TablaPadre.idPadre=a.acceso_padre
WHERE persona = 7 
ORDER BY a.acceso_padre ASC
```

Comment: no veo la necesidad por la cual agregar mas datos a la tabla, de esa forma se traeria el acceso padre pero dentro del mismo registro del acceso hijo, y lo que quiero es que sean registros por separado